# Need help to pop() elements from stack to linked list

Tags: java, stack, iteration

I have created a linked list and pushed them into my stack, but I cannot figure out how to pop them into a new linked list.

The code is below.

```
 import java.util.*;
```

```
public class StackRunner
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       LinkedList<String> myLinkedList1 = new LinkedList<String>();
       myLinkedList1.add("aaa");
       myLinkedList1.add("bbb");
       myLinkedList1.add("ccc");
       myLinkedList1.add("ddd");
       myLinkedList1.add("eee");
       // print the first linked list
       System.out.println("My Linked List 1:");
       System.out.println(myLinkedList1);


       Stack myStack = new Stack<String>();
       ListIterator iterator = myLinkedList1.listIterator(); 
       LinkedList<String> myLinkedList2 = new LinkedList<String>();
         while(iterator.hasNext())
        {   
            myStack.push(iterator.next());

        }
       while (!myStack.empty()){
         String s = myStack.pop();
         myLinkedList2.add(s);
              System.out.print(s+"");
              }



}
}
```

<pre>LinkedList<String> listTwo = LinkedList<String>(); 
while (!myStack.empty()){ 
listTwo.add(myStack.pop()); }<code>

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to need only a cast to compile and work...

`String s = (String) myStack.pop();`

I compile your code using Java7

Comment: didn't realize it was that simple thank you @Carlitos